# Adding a new automatic number sequence

Tags: microsoft-word

We write test case documents.

In these documents, each test case is numbered. E.g. Foobar-UI-1 to Foobar-UI-23 or Foobar-Device-1 to Foobar-Device-87

I'd like to autonumber these. I don't think I want just a new numbered list format, I want something like the list of figures - where figures (or test case) can be defined anywhere in the doc with other headings and paragraphs between them, and I can insert a "List of figures" table at the beginning.

So how do I do "test cases" and a "list of test-cases" table in the same way as figures work out of the box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming Word 2007, Go to `References`, `Insert Caption`. Click `New Label...`. Enter the title you want to use, such as "Test Case". That will insert the first item of the "Test Case" series. You can create as many different labels as you want.

Once labels are created, you can insert sequence items with them by coming back to `References`, `Insert Caption` and selecting the right label from the `Label` combo box.